# How to save image to Camera Roll using Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm creating an app using `Expo` to take picture, I'm already possible to save pictures to `FileSystem.documentDirectory`, but this is not what I want.

I tried to save image to `Camera Roll` using code like this:

```
import { CameraRoll } from 'react-native';
...
...
await CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(photo.uri);
```

But it's returning a warning me to use `react-native-cameraroll` instead of `react-native`. But as I see in the document of the `react-native-cameraroll`, it's seems not supporting `Expo`.

Is there any way to save image to Camera Roll in `Expo`?

Comment: Where did you see that it doesn't support Expo?

Comment: Because `react-native-cameraroll` need to `react-native link` on the setup, so I supposed that won't be able be done, the directory structure are different. But I didn't tried, it just didn't make sense to me.

Comment: You can take a look at expo 50 working answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78097172/10099510

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found the solution to this, instead of using `CameraRoll` you can use `MediaLibrary` to `MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(localUri)`

More details on [the documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/media-library/#medialibrarysavetolibraryasynclocaluri)

Comment: Thank you so much mate! Just saved my life here!

Comment: You're welcome! it works pretty well, Expo is amazing!

Comment: Thanks! Why the hell this is not documented on the expo camera docs page. everything I need is somehow not documented

Comment: I also encountered the same problem for at least two hours. Thanks to this answer it's sorted.

Comment: I'm so glad that this answer is helping someone.

Comment: I am also trying to save an image locally, I am using an expo image picker to take a picture, after that I am following MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(localUri) to save images locally, my question is where the image is saving?
Here is my expo link  https://snack.expo.io/@mamun_121/testing_snack

Comment: @MamunurRashid, I'm not sure, if you're asking for the path in the device, I think it depends on the OS, usually Android has folder where contains all the CameraRoll medias, I'm not familiar with iOS, but probably has something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes documents assume that we know more.

Please refer the following code snapshot.

```
const downloadPhoto = async (photoUrl) =>{
    const fileName = photoUrl.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
    let imageFullPathInLocalStorage = FileSystem.documentDirectory+fileName;
    return new Promise(async (resolve)=>{
        FileSystem.downloadAsync(
            photoUrl,
            imageFullPathInLocalStorage
        )
        .then(async ({ uri }) => {
            MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(imageFullPathInLocalStorage);
            return resolve(imageFullPathInLocalStorage);
        })
    });
  }
```

You should specify the local file URI to save the downloaded file.