# MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync Error: Unable to copy file into external storage

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-camera

I'm attempting to save a video to my cameraRoll in React Native on Android, console returns the video uri perfectly fine, but I get the error.

`Error: Unable to copy file into external storage.`

However, when putting the code on Snack, it works fine. Just not when I do a

`react-native run-android`

Here is the console logs

```
[Mon Aug 02 2021 21:03:30.108]  LOG      Video source:  file:///data/user/0/com.allies.ai/cache/Camera/74eb667a-a799-4f4e-8d80-98261580c36e.mp4
[Mon Aug 02 2021 21:03:32.222]  WARN     Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Unable to copy file into external storage.
promiseMethodWrapper@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:4552:45
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:109931:40
saveToLibraryAsync$@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:228365:95
tryCatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25289:23
invoke@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25462:32
tryCatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25289:23
invoke@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25362:30
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25392:19
tryCallTwo@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:27386:9
doResolve@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:27550:25
Promise@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:27409:14
callInvokeWithMethodAndArg@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25391:33
enqueue@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25396:157
async@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25413:69
saveToLibraryAsync@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:228352:38
recordVideo$@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:228022:48
tryCatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25289:23
invoke@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25462:32
tryCatch@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25289:23
invoke@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25362:30
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25372:21
tryCallOne@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:27377:16
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:27478:27
_callTimer@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30917:17
_callImmediatesPass@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30956:17
callImmediates@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:31173:33
__callImmediates@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:5034:35
http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:4820:34
__guard@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:5017:15
flushedQueue@http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:4819:21
flushedQueue@[native code]
invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
```

Here is the code on Snack:

https://snack.expo.dev/@ptang/camera

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

So for those with the similiar issue - Android 10+ now uses what's called Scope Storage. In short, there are restrictions on saving to your camera roll, there isn't any work around at this time of the answer for expo-camera OR react-native-cameraroll.

The only temporary fix is to add this following line:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml file, specifically in the activity section:

```
<manifest>
... 
 <application>
...
   <activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
   android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
...
   </activity>
...
 </application>
...
</manifest>
```

Comment: Any solutions for expo?

Comment: Doesn't work. Error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code to save remote images to gallery which works both on IOS and Android in Expo 50, today, 03/03/2024

```javascript
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";
import * as MediaLibrary from "expo-media-library";
import React from "react";
import { TouchableOpacity, Text } from "react-native";

export const ImageViewFooter = ({ gallery, imageIndex }) => {
  const DEFAULT_SAVE_IMAGE_TEXT = "Сохранить в галерею";
  const [saveImageText, setSaveImageText] = React.useState(DEFAULT_SAVE_IMAGE_TEXT);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      key={imageIndex}
      onPress={async () => {
        try {
          // Request device storage access permission
          const { status } = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
          if (status === "granted") {
            // Download image first
            setSaveImageText("Изображение сохраняется...");
            const date = dayjs().format("YYYYMMDDhhmmss");
            const fileUri = FileSystem.documentDirectory + `boom${date}.jpg`;
            const res = await FileSystem.downloadAsync(gallery[imageIndex].uri, fileUri);
            // Save image to media library
            await MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(res.uri);
            setTimeout(() => setSaveImageText(DEFAULT_SAVE_IMAGE_TEXT), 1500);
          } else {
            setSaveImageText("Доступ к галерее запрещен!");
            setTimeout(() => setSaveImageText(DEFAULT_SAVE_IMAGE_TEXT), 1500);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          setSaveImageText("Ошибка при сохранении!");
          setTimeout(() => setSaveImageText(DEFAULT_SAVE_IMAGE_TEXT), 1500);
        }
      }}
    >
      <Text
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: 50,
          color: "white",
          backgroundColor: "black",
          textAlign: "center",
          fontSize: 18,
          paddingTop: 8,
        }}
      >
        {saveImageText}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```