# I want to download an image with React Native Expo from a url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, download, expo

I want to download an image from a URL.

```
 const downloadImage = async () => {
        const permissions = await StorageAccessFramework.requestDirectoryPermissionsAsync();

        if (permissions.granted) {
            
            const uri = permissions.directoryUri;

            const files = await StorageAccessFramework.readDirectoryAsync(uri);
            try {
                await StorageAccessFramework.createFileAsync(permissions.directoryUri, 
                "myImage", "image/png")
                    .then((r) => {
                        console.log(r);
                        FileSystem.downloadAsync(
                            "my/image/url",
                            FileSystem.documentDirectory + "myImage.png"
                        )
                            .then(({ uri }) => {
                                console.log("Finished downloading to ", uri);
                            })
                            .catch((error) => {
                                console.error(error);
                            });
                    })
                    .catch((e) => {
                        console.log(e);
                    });
            } catch {
                console.log(e);
            }
            alert(`Files inside ${uri}:\n\n${JSON.stringify(files)}`);
        }
    };
```

Once the function runs everything goes well. A file with the name myImage.png is created. However, it's size is 0 Bytes and there is no image.

What am I missing?

Any help would be appreciated Thanks!

Comment: You can take a look at expo 50 working answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78097172/10099510

Answer (score 2):

We can use [MediaLibrary](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/media-library/) and [FileSystem](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/) for this.
Check the below example,

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
import moment from 'moment';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';

export default function DownloadImage() {

const imageUrl = { uri: "https://media.voguebusiness.com/photos/5ef6493adf1073db3375835d/master/pass/kanye-west-gap-news-voguebus-mert-alas-and-marcus-piggott-june-20-story.jpg" }

const handleDownload = async () => {
    let date = moment().format('YYYYMMDDhhmmss')
    let fileUri = FileSystem.documentDirectory + `${date}.jpg`;
    try {
        const res = await FileSystem.downloadAsync(imageUrl.uri, fileUri)
        saveFile(res.uri)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("FS Err: ", err)
    }
}

const saveFile = async (fileUri) => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.MEDIA_LIBRARY);
    if (status === "granted") {
        try {
            const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(fileUri);
            const album = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumAsync('Download');
            if (album == null) {
                await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync('Download', asset, false);
            } else {
                await MediaLibrary.addAssetsToAlbumAsync([asset], album, false);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Save err: ", err)
        }
    } else if (status === "denied") {
        alert("please allow permissions to download")
    }
}

return (
    <View>
        <Button
            title="Download"
            onPress={handleDownload}
        />
    </View>
    )
}
```